# GraphQL Gatsby Plugin Image set max-width to size of original image

Tags: graphql, gatsby, fancybox, gatsby-image

I am using **Google Photos** to host photos for a website I am managing, and accessing them via **GraphQL** and **Gastby** (gatsby-image-plugin)

The images are shown in a gallery, but open up in a light-box gallery slider - I'm using FancyApps/ui (v4.x). Anyway the maximum size of the images are the maximum size of the source set (i.e. 512px). This means on a big screen the full screen image looks small (only 512px wide).  You can see these values on the screen-grab below:

```
"original": {
  "width": 512,
  "height": 341
}
```

The original image is 1200px width, which is confirmed by the media metadata:

```
"mediaMetadata": {
  "height": "800",
  "width": "1200"
}"
```

Which is the same as images > sources > sizes:
`"sizes": "(min-width: 512px) 512px, 100vw"`

I realise I can force the value by specifying gatsbyImageSharp to have a width of 1200.

```
{
  allGooglePhotosAlbum(filter: {title: {eq: "assorted"}}) {
    nodes {
      title
      photos {
        file {
          childImageSharp {
            id
            gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, width: 1200)
            original {
              width
              height
            }
          }
        }
        mediaMetadata {
          height
          width
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However some of the images are not 1200px wide (i.e. the portrait images), I get the following warning:

```
The requested width "1200px" for a resolutions field for the file URL_HERE was larger than the actual image width of 512px! If possible, replace the current image with a larger one.
```

I don't like the warning, but more importantly I think this might make the height of the image too large to be displayed properly (i.e. either would be cropped or larger than the screen height - 100vh).

Surely there, should be a way to set the largest image width/height to the heights provided by the media metadata (i.e. the full un-adulterated image).

[image: GraphQL ScreenGrab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anyone else has this issue, I have managed to figure it out.  It turns out that it wasn't related to the graphQL query at all, but rather with the gatsby-source-google-photos plugin I was using.

The this plugin has the option to set the maxHeight and maxWidth - these values are both 512px by default. Which was why that was the maximum image width I was seeing in my query was 512px (when the original image was 1200px). [See the documentation](https://github.com/cedricdelpoux/gatsby-source-google-photos/blob/master/docs/options.md)

All I needed to do was to change these values to 1200px in my gatsby-config.js file and I got the larger images.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to play along with the width of the image rather than the [layout display](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#layout), otherwise you will face the issue you mention (some images has 1200 but not all of them, plus adding a scaling that may not fit all the images constraints).

That said, I think you can simply do something like:

```
{
  allGooglePhotosAlbum(filter: {title: {eq: "assorted"}}) {
    nodes {
      title
      photos {
        file {
          childImageSharp {
            id
            gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
            original {
              width
              height
            }
          }
        }
        mediaMetadata {
          height
          width
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The specs about `FULL_WIDTH`:

> Use this for images that are always displayed at the full width of the
> screen, such as banners or hero images. Like the constrained layout,
> this resizes to fit the container. However it is not restricted to a
> maximum size, so will grow to fill the container however large it is,
> maintaining its aspect ratio. **It generates several smaller image sizes
> for different screen breakpoints, so that the browser only needs to
> load one large enough to fit the screen**. You can pass a breakpoints
> prop if you want to specify the sizes to use, though in most cases you
> can allow it to use the default.

That way, the displayed images won't be constrained by their own constraints, but they will be by the container where they are displayed, allowing you to play around with CSS rules to customize them. In addition, the browser will only take the image that needs to fit the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a good idea, but unfortunately that just makes the sizes in sources (and fallback) to be 100vw, with the srcSet of the sources (and fallback) containing just a single string (the image with a width of 512px), even thought the mediaMetadata shows it as "1200" :/